# Outlook 2011 for Mac Outlook Anywhere

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-anywhere, outlook-2011

Since we've upgraded to Exchange 2010, I am unable to get Outlook Anywhere working for our Mac Office 2011 users. It works perfectly for our Windows users, but not the Outlook 2011 users.

How do I get this working?

Comment: What is the problem? Lets start with that type of basic information.

Comment: Per my original question, Outlook Anywhere  isn't working for any user who has Outlook 2011 for Mac. When they are at home on their Macs and they fire up Outlook 2011, it never connects. I have thumbed through many posts but haven't much related to this specific problem.

Comment: Right, but are there any error message or other things that might help point to the issue? If it just isn't connecting that doesn't give us anywhere near enough information to try and help you.

Comment: They can manually enter our OWA URL into the SERVER field and then it will connect, but when they come back to the office, that field gets auto set back to the internal URL (server.domain.local). Then they go back home and can't connect again (unless they manually configure the server settings). Outlook Anywhere worked fine for Mac users when we were on Exchange 2007, but not with Exchange 2010.

Comment: No error message that I can see so far. I just see the status on the bottom right saying "Connecting to "Companyname"... It says that forever.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Anywhere doesn't integrate as easily for Mac's as it does for PC's

See [this link](http://enterprisecomputer.com/blog/?p=18) for a quick fix - I have employed this in my office and it works well.

Comment: So, I know that if I manually enter the External URL into the server field in Outlook 2011, the client will connect. The problem is you have to do it manually (which means Outlook Anywhere isn't doing it's job). Again, this is just for the Mac users. As soon as the user comes back to the office, that field will get set back to the Internal URL. After they leave again and try connecting at home, Outlook Anywhere doesn't do it's job.

Comment: @user111503  And I guess having them use a real computer isn't an option, huh? :o